# XamlParseException was unhandled

Tags: wcf, xaml

I faced the problem debugging my WPF-WCF simple chat application. There's an exception like:

> Blockquote XamlParseException was unhandled. 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'ChatGUI.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

I see that's a XAML exception, so here's the XAML code listing:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/310851/XamlParseException-was-unhandled

Have you ever seen the same problem? I would be glad to see every useful advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XamlParseException can be a little bit misleading. Check if you're doing something in the constructor of your class MainWindow that throws an exception. This will cause the same behavior. Unfortunately the debugger won't break at the real initiater but show you this error.

E.g. use an try catch state statement in the constructor, the catch block will show you the exception.

Comment: The point is that there's no problem with this class prima facie. I'm a beginner in WCF programming so there's a big problem for me to find it. The class for checking: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/310851/XamlParseException-was-unhandled

Comment: There could be an error when you initiate the _backend member. Please try to catch it, maybe we know the reason then.

Comment: You know, that looks like true. There's an exception catching on: _backend = new ChatBackend.ChatBackend(this.DisplayMessage);

Comment: Then you know where you have to go into detail :)